# "Destination folder access denied" on a partition on MacBook Pro from Windows 8

Tags: macbook-pro, windows

I have bought a new MacBook Pro. I am from Windows background so I installed Windows 8.1. I wanted to have a partition that can be accessed from both OS so I created a partition using Bootcamp from Mac OS. On Mac, I can use the partition fully but on Windows side, I can only read the new partition. I can't paste any files or change anything on it. The error I am getting is "Destination folder access denied". I have given Admin right to move the files but still failed. I spent a while googling and there are many others getting this error but these are different scenarios mostly accessing networked drive and can't find any solution that would solve my problem. I tried to share the partition (on Windows) but that still doesn't work. Hope someone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: What format did you choose for the new partition?  Windows can't write to Apple Journaled partitions so you need to use something FAT-based if you want to write from both.

Comment: Yes .. that is exactly what happened .. Thanks .. you can promote your comment to an answer if you wish .. i will accept it .. thanks.

Comment: Deleted the data partition and created a new partition with MS DOS Fat format and my windows 8 won't boot anymore. Tried automatic repair as some suggested but failed so finally deleted Windows partition completely and installed it again from bootcamp. best just to keep a small memory stick for data :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows cannot write to Apple Journaled partitions.  OS X cannot write to NTFS. So you'll need to choose something FAT-based.

There are third-party solutions to allow writing of course but I've never found the performance hit to be worth versus just going with FAT.

Note that doing three partitions with Bootcamp can be tricky. I recommend so research on that subject.